# Return value shows error within success method of .ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax call in my coldfusion page which is as below:

```
function getData(paramValue)
{
    var URL = "/cfc/**somecfc.cfc**?method=**somemethod**";
    $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: URL,   
    data: ({ paramValue: paramValue}),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) { alert(data);},
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){                     
            alert("xhr.status = " + xhr.status);                     
            alert("thrownError = " + thrownError);                      }
    });
}
```

some method in somecfc returns a text value. When I try to view the data within success, it shows the following error:

`"<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>ERROR: . &lt;br /&gt;Element SETTINGS is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.</string></data></wddxPacket>"`

Since it shows the error from within **success**, there seems to be problem with the return data or ?

Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated.

the code in the cfc method is as follows:

```
<cffunction name="somemethod" access="remote" returntype="any" o>
    <cfargument name="paramValue" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfset var returnValue = "" />
        <cfquery name="someQry" datasource="#variables.settings['dsn']#"  >
            SELECT  value_name 
            FROM    valuesTbl 
            WHERE   value_Id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.paramValue#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        </cfquery>
        <cfset returnValue =  #someQry.value_name# />
    <cfreturn returnValue />
</cffunction>
```

returnValue variable has only 1 string value. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is going on in the method?

Comment: You'll need to post the code in your cfc, since that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: the code in the cfc method is as follows: 
    <cffunction name="somemethod" access="remote" returntype="any" o>
  <cfargument name="paramValue" type="string" required="yes" >
        <cfset var returnValue = "" />
            <cfquery name="someQry" datasource="#variables.settings['dsn']#"  >
    SELECT  value_name 
    FROM valuesTbl 
    WHERE value_Id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.paramValue#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
   </cfquery>
   <cfset returnValue =  #someQry.value_name# />
  <cfreturn returnValue />
    </cffunction>

returnValue variable has only 1 string value.

Answer (score 2):

You have 1 success and 1 failure going on.  The Ajax request went according to plan, you made a request (valid) and obtained a valid response (some text, xml specifically).  It appears that there was an exception thrown on the ColdFusion side that it was able to catch and convert to a response (the xml you received from you ajax request).

IE:  Your ajax request went well (returned HTTP 200), but something went wrong on the ColdFusion side.  You will only reach the error handler if there was an HTTP 500/400 series error.

Comment: When I use dataType: "text/html", then it goes to error block. And shows alert as xhr.status = 200 and "thrownError = No Conversion from text to text/html". So I am now confused whether there is an exception is from coldfusion side or jquery ajax side. 
Also, when I try to pull data from the same cfc and method from other coldfusion page without ajax, it works well.

Comment: Remember that your return header should have a MIME Type of text/html as well.  If the type you're asking for with Jquery doesn't match the type that is returned, you will get an error.  The 200 is from the server (it successfully generated a response).  The error was on the client side because the types mismatched.

Comment: We had the same "No conversion from text to text/html" error and submitted a bug on the jQuery site.  We were told to change the dataType from "text/html" to "html", and that corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion (by default) actually returns a status code of 200 with application errors, instead of the proper 500.x response.  $.ajax looks at the HTTP status code (<> 200) to determine whether to fire the "error" callback.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for responding to my question. the error was on coldfusion side. It was related to the DSN I was using by `#Application.Settings['DSN']#` which was not available remotely as it was out of the scope for this request.

Thanks again!